# Nifi DBCPConnectionPoolLookup fails to find DBCPService

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm attempting to use the DBCPConnectionPoolLookup processor to dynamically connect to multiple databases. I have verified the connection pools are valid. When dynamically setting the database.name property using an UpdateAttribute processor and running an ExecuteSQL processor I get *“No DBCPService found for database.name”*. I have logged the values of the DBCPConnectionPoolLookup processor’s database.name property prior to the step executing the SQL and I can see the name is changing to values corresponding to my connection pools (same pools validated when property was statically set). I am using nifi 1.21.0.

[Lookup config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB0JH.png)
[Update Attribute config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baa8F.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your Lookup config?

Comment: Also your UpdateAttribute config? I tried this and it worked for me, I'm thinking maybe the UpdateAttribute is problematic.

Comment: I hope I provided what your asking for.

Comment: Your UpdateAttribute appears to be using JSONPath where it needs to be using NiFi Expression Language, so try changing it to ${CONNECTIONPOOL_NAME}

Comment: Thanks - I made the suggested change and re-ran and got the same results. I verified the old config was not cached. I can still see in the log that ${DBCPConnectionPoolLookup.database.name} is equal to the DBCPService I expect.

Comment: mattyb - I incorrectly stated I was able to use the lookup service when statically setting the database.name property in my original post - I've corrected it. I'm still unable to get the lookup service to work.

Comment: In the Lookup config you are using a parameter not a variable, and you are using the ID of the DBCPConnectionPool. You will instead want to use the name of the DBCPConnectionPool which means each of your pools will need a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

I was making two mistakes: 1 - I did not have my connection pool names registered as properties of my connection pool lookup controller and 2 - in my EvaluateJsonPath processor I needed to set the Destination property to “flowfile-attribute”. Once I made these changes it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. I had the same error. When I add the connection pool names in the properties of the connection pool lookup, it worked.
The names must be added as a property, with an alias (key) and the name of the DBCPConnectionPool (value).